# httprequest handle time delays till having response

Tags: android, handler, postdelayed

I have an application that calls a function to send JSON object to a REST API, my problem is how can I handle time delays and repeat this function till i have a response from the server in case of interrupted network connexion ??
I try to use the Handler but i don't know how to stop it when i get a response !!!

here's my function that is called when button clicked :

```
 protected void sendJson(final String name, final String email, final String homepage,final Long unixTime,final String bundleId) {
    Thread t = new Thread() {

        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare(); //For Preparing Message Pool for the child Thread
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); //Timeout Limit
            HttpResponse response;
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            //creating meta object
            JSONObject metaJson = new JSONObject();

            try {
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://util.trademob.com:5000/cards");

                metaJson.put("time", unixTime);
                metaJson.put("bundleId", bundleId);

                json.put("name", name);
                json.put("email", email);
                json.put("homepage", homepage);
                //add the meta in the root object
                json.put("meta", metaJson);


                StringEntity se = new StringEntity( json.toString());  
                se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                post.setEntity(se);
                String authorizationString = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(
                        ("tester" + ":" + "tm-sdktest").getBytes(),
                        Base64.NO_WRAP); //Base64.NO_WRAP flag
                post.setHeader("Authorization", authorizationString);

                response = client.execute(post);
                String temp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), temp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            Looper.loop(); //Loop in the message queue
        }
    };

    t.start();      
}
```

Comment: I would implement a listener Interface which you can pass to your method and then depending on the response error / success invoke appropriate method from the listener which can run the API call again in case of an error.

Comment: you make things more complicat for me, I'm a little bit new in android, can you please make some code, thank you